# Aggregating on 2 columns and turning into columns on another

Tags: dataframe, apache-spark, pyspark, count, aggregate

I have the following dataframe of HTTP requests with columns `IP`, `Timestamp`, `user_agent` and `hostname`:

| IP | Timestamp | user_agent | hostname |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1.1.1.1 | 1656758570 | ua1 | hostname1 |
| 1.1.1.1 | 1656758580 | ua2 | hostname2 |
| 1.1.1.1 | 1656758570 | ua3 | hostname1 |
| 1.1.1.1 | 1656758580 | ua1 | hostname3 |
| 2.2.2.2 | 1656758580 | ua3 | hostname2 |
| 2.2.2.2 | 1656758580 | ua1 | hostname1 |
| 2.2.2.2 | 1656758590 | ua3 | hostname1 |
| 2.2.2.2 | 1656758590 | ua2 | hostname3 |
| 2.2.2.2 | 1656758590 | ua1 | hostname2 |

I want to group the data by the `IP` column, then inside each group to aggregate on the `Timestamp` column, calculate `countDistinct` values for the other columns (`user_agent` and `hostname`) that have the same `Timestamp` value, and then transform the aggregated data into new columns. Namely, I want the result dataframe to look like this:

| IP | 1656758570_uniue_user_agent | 1656758570_uniue_hostname | 1656758580_uniue_user_agent | 1656758580_uniue_hostname | 1656758590_uniue_user_agent | 1656758590_uniue_hostname |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1.1.1.1 | 2 | 1 | 2 | 2 | 0 | 0 |
| 2.2.2.2 | 0 | 0 | 2 | 2 | 3 | 3 |

Is there a convenient way to do this instead of multiple `withColumn` calls?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can insert a [**`pivot`**](https://spark.apache.org/docs/3.1.1/api/python/reference/api/pyspark.sql.GroupedData.pivot.html#pyspark.sql.GroupedData.pivot) between `groupBy` and `agg`

```py
from pyspark.sql import functions as F
df = spark.createDataFrame(
    [('1.1.1.1', 1656758570, 'ua1', 'hostname1'),
     ('1.1.1.1', 1656758580, 'ua2', 'hostname2'),
     ('1.1.1.1', 1656758570, 'ua3', 'hostname1'),
     ('1.1.1.1', 1656758580, 'ua1', 'hostname3'),
     ('2.2.2.2', 1656758580, 'ua3', 'hostname2'),
     ('2.2.2.2', 1656758580, 'ua1', 'hostname1'),
     ('2.2.2.2', 1656758590, 'ua3', 'hostname1'),
     ('2.2.2.2', 1656758590, 'ua2', 'hostname3'),
     ('2.2.2.2', 1656758590, 'ua1', 'hostname2')],
    ['IP', 'Timestamp', 'user_agent', 'hostname'])

df = (df
    .groupBy('IP')
    .pivot('Timestamp')
    .agg(F.countDistinct('user_agent').alias('unique_user_agent'),
         F.countDistinct('hostname').alias('unique_hostname'))
    .fillna(0)
)

df.show()
# +-------+----------------------------+--------------------------+----------------------------+--------------------------+----------------------------+--------------------------+
# |     IP|1656758570_unique_user_agent|1656758570_unique_hostname|1656758580_unique_user_agent|1656758580_unique_hostname|1656758590_unique_user_agent|1656758590_unique_hostname|
# +-------+----------------------------+--------------------------+----------------------------+--------------------------+----------------------------+--------------------------+
# |2.2.2.2|                           0|                         0|                           2|                         2|                           3|                         3|
# |1.1.1.1|                           2|                         1|                           2|                         2|                           0|                         0|
# +-------+----------------------------+--------------------------+----------------------------+--------------------------+----------------------------+--------------------------+
```

Answer (score 1):

Use list comprehension to pass a wildcard and pivot the count. Code below;

```
(df
    .groupBy('IP')
    .pivot('Timestamp')
    .agg(*[F.countDistinct(col(x)).alias(f'unique_{x}') for x in df.drop('Timestamp').columns]
        )
    .fillna(0)
).show()



   +-------+--------------------+----------------------------+--------------------------+--------------------+----------------------------+--------------------------+--------------------+----------------------------+--------------------------+
|     IP|1656758570_unique_IP|1656758570_unique_user_agent|1656758570_unique_hostname|1656758580_unique_IP|1656758580_unique_user_agent|1656758580_unique_hostname|1656758590_unique_IP|1656758590_unique_user_agent|1656758590_unique_hostname|
+-------+--------------------+----------------------------+--------------------------+--------------------+----------------------------+--------------------------+--------------------+----------------------------+--------------------------+
|2.2.2.2|                   0|                           0|                         0|                   1|                           2|                         2|                   1|                           3|                         3|
|1.1.1.1|                   1|                           2|                         1|                   1|                           2|                         2|                   0|                           0|                         0|
+-------+--------------------+----------------------------+--------------------------+--------------------+----------------------------+--------------------------+--------------------+----------------------------+--------------------------+
```